# Spellchecker misses misspelled words

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I have downloaded additional [Slovenian dictionary package](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/slovenian-dictionary-package-slovenski-paket-slovarjev) for TeXstudio and when I run spellchecking, I thought it worked fine, since it pointed out some misspelled words and came up with possible replacements.

> The problem is that spellckecker missed some obviously misspelled words.

I made a test and added a gibberish word `asdasdasd` in the middle of the document. Then I clicked `Tools > Check Spelling...`, but I got a response `No more misspelled words`, even marking all the words with `CTRL + a` did not help. Nothing did (like placing mouse cursor in the beginning of the document etc.), unless I marked only the word `asdasdasd` (by moving mouse over it). In that case, spell checker recognised the misspelled word.

I also copied an article from English Wikipedia, then added the gibberish word in it (and changed language settings in `Options > General`) and checking worked fine (but that doesn't prove anything, since the Slovene checker aslo noticed some misspeled words).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem is interesting, but I'm afraid it is off topic for this site, because TeXStudio just uses the spell checkers provided by OpenOffice.org and it has no control over them (apart perhaps the possibility of locally adding words to the dictionary, which I'm not sure of).

Comment: @egreg Well, I thought maybe somebody has encountered simimlar problems ...

Comment: @egrer Do you happen to know where can I ask this question?